# mysql JOIN query returns multiple times the same rows

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to display all the generic slopes (from `game_slopes`) from sector 1 that are built (i.e. present in `game_created_slopes`) and status_id =1.

```
CREATE TABLE `game_created_slopes` (
  `id_created_slopes` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_player` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_slope` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `custom_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `slope_condition` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `id_status` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `end_construction` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `game_created_slopes` (`id_created_slopes`, `id_player`, `id_slope`, `custom_name`, `slope_condition`, `id_status`, `end_construction`) VALUES
(168, 46, 6, 'Slope 24', 50, 1, '2016-05-17 17:01:25'),
(170, 46, 1, 'Slope 1', 1, 1, '2016-06-06 18:35:22'),
(172, 46, 7, 'Slope 3', 100, 1, '2016-06-08 21:48:43');


CREATE TABLE `game_slopes` (
  `id_slope` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_sector` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name_english` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `name_french` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `length` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_difficulty` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cost` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `building_time` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `reputation` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


INSERT INTO `game_slopes` (`id_slope`, `id_sector`, `name_english`, `name_french`, `length`, `id_difficulty`, `cost`, `building_time`, `reputation`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'Slope 1', 'Piste 1', 2000, 1, 1000000, 13, 3000),
(6, 1, 'Slope 2', 'Piste 2', 1000, 2, 100000, 15, 5000),
(7, 2, 'Slope 3', 'Piste 3', 1400, 3, 200000, 5, 8000),
(8, 1, 'Slope 5', 'Piste 5', 1456, 4, 105000, 20, 5040);
```

Unfortunately the two results that should be returned (ID 168 and 170) are returned **three times each**. I noticed that if `game_created_slopes` contains 5 rows, then the two IDs will be returned **5 times each**.

(ID 172 is in sector 2 so it's not returned)

My query:

```
$this->db->distinct('game_slopes.id_slope, game_slopes.id_sector, game_created_slopes.id_slope, game_created_slopes.id_created_slopes, game_created_slopes.id_player');
$this->db->from('game_slopes, game_created_slopes');
$this->db->join('game_created_slopes as created_slopes_tbl', 'game_slopes.id_slope = created_slopes_tbl.id_slope', 'inner');
$this->db->where('created_slopes_tbl.id_status', '1');
$this->db->where('game_slopes.id_sector', '1);
$this->db->where('created_slopes_tbl.id_player', $currentUserID);
$query = $this->db->get();
```

PHP code:

```
$num_slopes_for_this_sector = $this->Model->get_slopes_($currentUserID);

foreach ($num_slopes_for_this_sector->result() as $row){
      echo '<br>SECTOR :'. $i;
      echo '<br>id_created_slopes:'.$row->id_created_slopes;
}
```

What is wrong with my query? It should return only two IDs.

Comment: Not criticizing, just wondering out of curiosity, why would you build the query that way instead of just a more direct `SELECT fields FROM joined tables WHERE conditions met` approach? It looks like a fairly simple sql query was chopped up and shuffled.

Comment: I appreciate the comment, actually I'm open to any suggestion to make the query simpler. Do you have an example to provide for such syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use from a single table beacuse you use join for the second

```
 $this->db->from('game_slopes');
```

If you leave the two table you obtain a cartesian product for both the table

Answer (score 0):

To show a direct translation, line for line...

```
SELECT DISTINCT game_slopes.id_slope, game_slopes.id_sector, game_created_slopes.id_slope, game_created_slopes.id_created_slopes, game_created_slopes.id_player
FROM game_slopes, game_created_slopes
INNER JOIN game_created_slopes as created_slopes_tbl ON game_slopes.id_slope = created_slopes_tbl.id_slope
WHERE created_slopes_tbl.id_status = 1
AND game_slopes.id_sector = 1
AND created_slopes_tbl.id_player = $currentUserID
;
```

I'd format it more like this though (also removing the accidental cross join, and updating the reference/alias used)

```
SELECT DISTINCT game_slopes.id_slope, game_slopes.id_sector
   , created_slopes_tbl.id_slope, created_slopes_tbl.id_created_slopes
   , created_slopes_tbl.id_player
FROM game_slopes
    INNER JOIN game_created_slopes AS created_slopes_tbl 
       ON game_slopes.id_slope = created_slopes_tbl.id_slope
WHERE created_slopes_tbl.id_status = 1
   AND game_slopes.id_sector = 1
   AND created_slopes_tbl.id_player = $currentUserID
;
```

Finally, though I am not completely familiar with php; I'd replace the `$currentUserID` with `?` and turn it into a parameterized query.

---

Though, I'm a lazy typist (and have had aliases be helpful later when tables need replaced with subqueries).

```
SELECT DISTINCT gs.id_slope, gs.id_sector
   , gcs.id_slope, gcs.id_created_slopes
   , gcs.id_player
FROM game_slopes AS gs
    INNER JOIN game_created_slopes AS gcs
       ON gs.id_slope = gcs.id_slope
WHERE gcs.id_status = 1
   AND gs.id_sector = 1
   AND gcs.id_player = $currentUserID
;
```